# Shapes (None, 40, 100) and (None, 64, 100) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying simple model for prediction sha1 hashes of strings, which should take the dataset consisting of string:sha1_string.

Dataset is generated in code.

I am trying to train model, but it fails with error

```
Shapes (None, 40, 100) and (None, 64, 100) are incompatible
```

Below is my code that fails.

```
import hashlib
import random
import string
import csv

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import argmax
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Input
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Flatten, TimeDistributed, RepeatVector

chars = sorted(set(string.printable))
random.seed(0)
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

def convert_to_onehot(data):
    integer_encoded = [char_to_int[char] for char in data]
    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in integer_encoded:
        letter = [0 for _ in range(len(chars))]
        letter[value] = 1
        onehot_encoded.append(letter)
    return onehot_encoded

def convert_from_onehot(data):
    inverted = "".join([int_to_char[argmax(value)] for value in data])
    return inverted

def create_dataset():
    dataset_file = open("dataset.csv", "w")
    dataset_writer = csv.writer(dataset_file, delimiter=":")
    for i in range(1000):
        str = []
        for x in range(64):
            str.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
        str = ''.join(str)
        hash = hashlib.sha1(str.encode()).hexdigest()
        dataset_writer.writerow([str, hash])
    dataset_file.close()

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    reg = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)
    model.add(Dense(160, input_shape=(64,len(chars)), kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(640, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(320, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(160, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(len(chars), kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg, activation='softmax'))
    #opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    opt = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['Accuracy', 'Precision'])
    return model

create_dataset()
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", sep=":", header=None)
dataset = df.values
train = dataset[:,0]
test = dataset[:,1]


X = np.zeros((len(train), 64, len(chars)))
y = np.zeros((len(test), 40, len(chars)))
for i, data in enumerate(train):
    X[i] = convert_to_onehot(data)
for i, data in enumerate(test):
    y[i] = convert_to_onehot(data)

model = create_model()
model.summary()
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2, epochs=100, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Try to avoid naming your X "train" and your y "test"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you flatten your input

```
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], -1)
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], -1)
```

and adjust the input shape of the first layer from
`(64,len(chars))` to  `(64*len(chars),)` and the output size of the last layer from `len(chars)` to `40*len(chars)` accordingly.

Comment: After that loss rapidly grows per epoch, last epoch has "loss: 3709047720040726528.0000 ".